# Is this the right way of solving $x^2y''-xy'+y=8x^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The original equation is:

$$x^2y''-xy'+y=8x^3$$

My workflow (Warning: quite long)

---

$\begin{align} y &= x^k \\
y' &= kx^{k-1} \\
y'' &= k(k-1)k^{k-2} \end{align}$

after symplyfiyng I got:

$$k^2-2k + 1 = 0 \tag{1}$$

with double root $k_{1,2} = 1$

So the general solution is: $$y(x) = C_1x+C_2x\ln|x|$$

---

After that I rewrote equation $(1)$ as:

$$y'' -2y'+y = 8x^3 \tag{2}$$

and as right side of $(2)$ is the cubic polynomial,  the particular solution will be:

$$\begin{align} y_p &= Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+ D \\
y'_p &= 3Ax^2 + 2Bx +C \\
y''_p &= 6Ax + 2B \end{align}$$

After applying Undetermined Coefficients methos I got the system:

$$\begin{cases} A = 1 \\ B = -6 \\ C = -30 \\ D = -48 \end{cases}$$

Finally $y_p = x^3-6x^2-30x-48$

And the answer is $y(x) = C_1x+C_2x\ln|x| + y_p$

---

**so my questions are:**

1.) Did I do this right? (My book's answer mentioned $x = e^t$ substitution, so answer looks different, but can shown way be accepted as the right answer, though?

2.) A bit of off-topic in the end, but could these substitutions be applied if for example $(1)$ had  the complex-conjugate roots? (Some resources say yes, some no, so I am totally confused).

Comment: I guess the particular solution is wrong. If you plug in $y_p(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ into $x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=8x^3$ you will get the system $4A=8$ and $B=D=0$. Here $C$ is arbitrary because $Cx$ solves the homogeneous part. The solution is now $y_p(x)=2x^3$.

Comment: There is something wrong with the solution of the homogeneous part. See the answer of Nicolas Francois below

Comment: Got it! I had substituted things into equation which I denoted as $(2)$, and I did not think about the original one, that is what I had missed.

Comment: @Fakemistake, yes, you sre right, I got the solution now, will mark your answer as accepted, despite it shows the other way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big Hint:** (with the given substitution $x=e^t$ above)
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=\frac{y'(t)}{e^t}\\
y''(x)&=\frac{y''(t)}{e^{2t}}-\frac{y'(t)}{e^{2t}}
\end{align}
You will get
\begin{align}
y''(t)-2y'(t)+y(t)=8e^{3t}
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know that, it is caused by $x = e^t$ substitution :), but I am about another substitutions :)

Comment: I think you meant to write $8e^{3t}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales of course it's $8e^{3t}$. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

try $y_P=Ax^3$ for the particular solution.

Comment: you can try this also, then you will get $$B=C=D=0$$

Comment: I thought any polynomial should be expanded to the full one, like if we have only $$x^2$$ then $$Ax^2+Bx +C $$ and it the actual example there is $x^3$ so it should be written like $$Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$$ Is not this correct?

Comment: so we only take the coefficients from variables that match the variables power of the original solution, and the rest can just be omited without fear of loosing anything?

Comment: @M.Mass When there's a polynomial of degree $m$ on the right hand side, you have to take the full ansatz $y_p(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$ for the particular solution of the ode. In your own words, you have to take $y_p(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution of the form $y=x^k$ for the homogeneous equation , as you did, you find $y=Cx$.

Now let's make the constant dance : put $y=zx$ with $z$ a function. You have $$y'=z+xz',\ y''=2z'+xz''$$
so substituting in the homogeneous equation :
$$3x^2z'+x^3z''=0\iff (x^3z')'=0\iff x^3z'=C\iff z=\frac{C'}{x^2}+C''$$
Therefore, a solution for the homogeneous equation is 
$$y=\frac{C'}{x}+C''x$$
Remains to find a solution for the base equation. You can use the usual method, but here, as suggested, looking for a solution of the form $y=Ax^3$ is successful : you find $A=2$, so a complete solution on either $]-\infty,0[$ or $]0,+\infty[$ is 
$$y=2x^3+\frac{C}{x}+C'x$$
Of course, as the equation is an Euler equation, putting $x=\pm e^t$ immediately transforms the homogeneous equation in a linear one, so it may be a better method.
Hope I didn't make too many mistakes...